# Is the cardinality of a segment of some well-ordered set strictly less than the cardinality of the set itself?

Tags: set-theory

When I was reading some papers, I encounter some arguments:

"(Assuming Axiom of Choice) We can well-order our set $A$ in a way such that every proper initial segment has cardinalities strictly less than $|A|$". I can't figure out why we can do that.

The standard definition of the cardinality of any well-ordered set is the unique initial ordinal equipotent to $A$, where the initial ordinal is some ordinal $\alpha$ that is not equipotent to any ordinal $\beta < \alpha$.

Note: I am aware that no well-ordered set is order-isomorphic to any of its proper intial segments, but here, we are considering "equipotent", not "order-isomorphic".

Comment: If a set $X$ is infinite (uncountable), there always exists a bijection between $X$ and a proper subset of itself.

Comment: @math-physicist Are you sure, is there a bijection between $\{0\}$ and ${\mathbb{R}}$

Comment: @math-physicist: there is always exist bijections between $X$ and proper subsets of $X$, but here the subset is required to be a proper initial subset of $X$ under a given ordering and that restricts the possibilities. If you equip $X$ with the ordering of its cardinal, then no proper initial subset will be equipotent with $X$.

Comment: @Hamilton: math-physicist means "and some proper subset of itself" "and any proper subset of itself".

Comment: Please insert "not" between the two quoted phrases to make sense of my last comment. Too late to edit.

Comment: Yeah, I think people will insert a "not" when they see and try to make sense of this, at least I did it.

Comment: Compare $\omega$ and $\omega + 1$, which illustrate the possibilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is infinite you can well-order it in the order type of its cardinal.  All the initial segments of that cardinal have strictly smaller cardinality than the cardinal itself.

An example is the situation for a countable set.  You can order it in type $\omega$.  All the initial segments are finite in length, so of strictly smaller cardinality than the set itself.